# How can I hide navigationBar -> Overlay Label but as an image, like Airbnb?

Tags: ios, swift, animation, navigationbar

I've experimented a little bit to copy (or at least to have a similar working example) the airbnb navigationBar. For those who doesn't know the app please see the following screenshots:

[image: airbnb navigationBar start]:

[image: airbnb navigationBar overlay]

As you may see the navigationBar is at first hidden and then is behind the image but overlays the heading label. I really like the animation how the navigationbar transition smoothly to the front.

I thought to do this with

1. Hide navigationBar
2. At the exact position beginn with fading in the navigationBar: Make navigationBar transparent and the increase the alpha
3. At the end of the animation show the default navigationBar

The implementation looks like: https://github.com/mbecker/AirbnbCopy

```
import UIKit

private let kTableHeaderHeight: CGFloat = 300.0
private let kTableHeaderCutAway: CGFloat = 60.0

class MainViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var headerView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
    @IBOutlet weak var parkHeading: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var parkImage: UIImageView!
    
    var headerMaskLayer: CAShapeLayer!
    // create background images for the navigation bar
    var navBarImage = UIImage().imageWithColor(UIColor(red:0.11, green:0.64, blue:0.98, alpha:0.0))
    var gradientImage32 = UIImage().imageWithColor(UIColor(red:0.11, green:0.64, blue:0.98, alpha:0.0))
    
    let image = UIImage(named: "bg-addo")
    let overlay: UIView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height, 400))
    
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        scrollView.delegate = self
        
        // Adjust view
        self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
        
        // NavigationBar
        let attrs = [
            NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.blackColor(),
            NSFontAttributeName : UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Bold", size: 17)!
        ]
        self.navigationController!.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = attrs
        self.navigationController!.navigationBar.hidden = true
        self.navigationController!.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(navBarImage, forBarMetrics: .Default)
        self.navigationController!.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(navBarImage, forBarMetrics: .Compact)
//        self.navigationController!.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
        self.navigationController!.navigationBar.barStyle = .Default
        
        
        // Header
        overlay.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.04, green:0.28, blue:0.44, alpha:0.4)
        parkImage.addSubview(overlay)
        parkImage.image = image?.imageWithAlpha(1)
        
        headerMaskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        headerMaskLayer.fillColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
        
        headerView.layer.mask = headerMaskLayer
        updateHeaderView()
        
    }
    
    func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        
        let heightShowNavBarStart   = kTableHeaderHeight - kTableHeaderCutAway - parkHeading.frame.height - 66
        let heightShowNavBarEnd     = kTableHeaderHeight - kTableHeaderCutAway - 66
        
        
        print("scrollView.contentOffset.y   -   \(scrollView.contentOffset.y)")
        print("heightShowNavBarStart        -   \(heightShowNavBarStart)")
        print("heightShowNavBarEnd          -   \(heightShowNavBarEnd)")
        
        
        
        let base        = parkHeading.frame.height
        let counter     = heightShowNavBarEnd - scrollView.contentOffset.y
        var alpha       = counter / base
        var navigationBarHidden = false;
        
        if(scrollView.contentOffset.y >= heightShowNavBarStart && scrollView.contentOffset.y <= heightShowNavBarEnd){
            
        } else if (scrollView.contentOffset.y < heightShowNavBarStart ){
            navigationBarHidden = true
            alpha = 1
        } else if(scrollView.contentOffset.y > heightShowNavBarEnd) {
            navigationBarHidden = false
            alpha = 0
        }
        print("alpha                - \(alpha)")
        print("navigationBarHidden  - \(navigationBarHidden)")
        
        
        self.navigationController!.navigationBar.hidden = navigationBarHidden
        
        if(!navigationBarHidden && alpha == 0){
            // Show navigationBar && hide headerView parkImage
            parkImage.hidden = true
            self.navigationController!.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(nil, forBarMetrics: .Default)
            self.navigationController!.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(nil, forBarMetrics: .Compact)
            self.navigationController!.navigationBar.barStyle = .Default
        } else {
            parkImage.hidden = false
            parkImage.image = image?.imageWithAlpha(alpha)
            navBarImage = UIImage().imageWithColor(UIColor(red:0.96, green:0.96, blue:0.98, alpha: 1 - alpha))
            self.navigationController!.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(navBarImage, forBarMetrics: .Default)
            self.navigationController!.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(navBarImage, forBarMetrics: .Compact)
            overlay.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.04, green:0.28, blue:0.44, alpha: alpha * 0.4)
        }
        
        
    }
    
    func updateHeaderView(){
        let effectiveHeight = kTableHeaderHeight-kTableHeaderCutAway/2
        var headerRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: -effectiveHeight, width: scrollView.bounds.width, height: kTableHeaderHeight)
        if scrollView.contentOffset.y < -effectiveHeight {
            headerRect.origin.y = scrollView.contentOffset.y
            headerRect.size.height = -scrollView.contentOffset.y + kTableHeaderCutAway/2
        }
        
        headerView.frame = headerRect
        
        let path = UIBezierPath()
        path.moveToPoint(CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
        path.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: headerRect.width, y: 0))
        path.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: headerRect.width, y: headerRect.height))
        path.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: 0, y: headerRect.height-kTableHeaderCutAway))
        headerMaskLayer?.path = path.CGPath
    }
    
}

extension UIImage {
    
    func imageWithColor(colour: UIColor) -> UIImage {
        let rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1)
        
        // Create a 1x1 pixel content
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, false, 0.0)
        colour.setFill()
        UIRectFill(rect)
        
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return image
    }
    
    func imageWithAlpha(alpha: CGFloat) -> UIImage {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, scale)
        drawAtPoint(CGPointZero, blendMode: .Normal, alpha: alpha)
        let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return newImage
    }
    
}
```

I think the animation is not very smooth and at some point the header image is not set back to the top of the screen.

Has anyone an idea how to create such an navigationBar?

Answer (score 3):

This is exactly what you want you it allows you to create header bars with flexible heights. Often, this sort of UI paradigm is used to hide "chrome" and make room for more content as a user is scrolling.

https://github.com/bryankeller/BLKFlexibleHeightBar/

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for the link! The airbnb navigationBar is vice versa; the navigationBar is hidden at the start and appears when the end of the image is at the middle of the navigatioBar. Additionally it overlays not the image but the rest.